# Drush hangs when trying to bootstrap Drupal

Tags: 7, drush

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with the 14.04 backports for Drush (meaning we are running Drush 5.10.0)

After importing the database (with drush sqlc < dump.sql), Drupal is no longer able to be bootstrapped by Drush.

```
drupal-site@uat-previewweb1:/var/www/drupal/uat-preview/current$ drush st -v -d
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 3.81 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 4.04 MB] [bootstrap]
Loading drushrc "/etc/drush/drushrc.php" into "system" scope. [0.01 sec, 4.04 MB]                                                                            [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.10.0-commandfiles-0-42f7d1cb79623ad6de6c23932c9a4e2b [0.02 sec, 4.07 MB]                                                                        [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.06 sec, 9.04 MB]                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.08 sec, 9.04 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.31 root directory at /var/www/drupal/uat-preview/releases/20140911-4 [0.09 sec, 10.69 MB]                                          [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.09 sec, 10.7 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site uat-preview at sites/default [0.09 sec, 10.7 MB]                                                                                [notice]
Cache HIT cid: 5.10.0-commandfiles-2-c32acd775c18a90c5b41d0fc9accf5ab [0.09 sec, 10.71 MB]                                                                       [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.1 sec, 10.75 MB]                                                                          [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.1 sec, 10.81 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.1 sec, 10.81 MB]                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.12 sec, 11.92 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
```

The command hangs here and does not return.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? Is it worth it to stray from debian packages and run Drush 6.4.0 here?

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, the issue was with an incorrectly configured memcache server settings, the Drupal environment in question was attempting to communicate with a memcache instance that had a firewall dropping all connections.

The fix was to configure memcache servers in the Drupal settings file. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Drush 5 is no longer supported, so I would recommend installing Drush 6 per the instructions in the README on the project page.  My guess is that Drush 6 will behave the same for you here, but it might be worth a try.  (If you are running Drupal 8, you **must** run the master branch of Drush, though.)

Regarding your specific problem above, a lot can go wrong if the versions of your modules is no longer in sync with the versions of the table schemas in your database.  If the database is OLDER than the code, you could try running `drush updatedb` immediately after you import the database.

If that does not help, it's hard to tell from the information available what could be causing the hang-up.  You'll have to dive in deeper and find out where in the code the bootstrap is having trouble, and isolate from there.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Do you know of any debian package repositories for Drush 6.x?

Comment: I thought Anarcat was maintaining these in Debian backports, but could not find any in a casual search. Installing via composer is probably best.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be any Drush 6.x packages for Debian anywhere.  You can find Drush via Composer w/ Puppet here: https://github.com/greg-1-anderson/ogm-postfix-environment.  The Drush and Composer modules are inlined here; these are a work-in-progress that I will factor out once finished. Having a package is better for keeping things up to date, but installing from composer in this way is a reasonable alternative when the version of the code you need isn't available in a package yet.