# Drush 8 hangs with any command

Tags: drush, 8

Up until recently, I've been using version 6 of drush, and it worked like a charm. Since I started delving into Drupal 8, I installed drush 7 on my Mac using the [install instructions](http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/#installupgrade-a-global-drush) (using Composer) for global drush. Initially, it was fine, but whenever I try to run it now, it just hangs. When I run it with -d, it gets this far:

```
Using the Drush script found at /Users/steve/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher using pcntl_exec
```

Running `which drush` shows the correct path  (`/Users/steve/.composer/vendor/bin/drush`), but like I said, running drush by itself or with any other command, it just hangs. From what I understand, the only error logging is to the screen, but since there's nothing being displayed to the screen, I'm not sure where to look. I don't have memcache installed (unlike [this guy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130725/drush-hangs-while-executing-any-command)), so I know that's not the problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I am using Drush 8 not Drush 7 (I fixed the title accordingly). After a couple days, it's back to hanging again, and even using `-d` shows nothing.

Comment: I have the same using Drush 7 :-(

Answer (score 1):

Only Drush 8 is compatible with Drupal 8. See http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility

Comment: I updated my post (and title) above - I am actually using Drush 8.

Comment: Are you chasing Drush master? Alternatively, what Drush version are you using? (`$ drush --version`). You could also try and quickly test with the PHAR alternative to rule out any issue with your composer install.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the Stack Exchange effect (post a question, and the problem is solved) worked. Actually I just restarted my computer (the Microsoft method of support), and it's now working fine.